# soft wave effect on SVG rope

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I'm doing an SVG animation and to be complete, just missing the rope animation

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #364254;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1445.0834 580.2761">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_150"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 150"
          x1="3.2814"
          y1="453.8773"
          x2="921.2548"
          y2="453.8773"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#f27075"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5248"
            stop-color="#2d6cea"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5932"
            stop-color="#457dec"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7376"
            stop-color="#82a8f3"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.9447"
            stop-color="#e4ecfc"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_16"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 16"
          x1="939.9244"
          y1="351.193"
          x2="1492.4711"
          y2="243.7888"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.1341"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0.7621"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4043"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0.3478"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.6262"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0.0928"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7707"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <filter
          id="AI_Desfoquegaussiano_4"
          name="AI_Desfoquegaussiano_4"
        >
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="4" />
        </filter>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient"
          x1="1021.6008"
          y1="714.8803"
          x2="1021.6008"
          y2="491.971"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#b9b9bd"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5039"
            stop-color="#fee7d5"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-2"
          x1="1015.1188"
          y1="715.6549"
          x2="1015.1188"
          y2="662.471"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#401737"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#2d6cea"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-3"
          x1="1020.4081"
          y1="701.4192"
          x2="1020.4081"
          y2="673.7128"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-4"
          x1="1042.4303"
          y1="595.163"
          x2="1042.4303"
          y2="578.9113"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-5"
          x1="1010.7335"
          y1="660.0198"
          x2="1010.7335"
          y2="649.7516"
          gradientTransform="translate(1576.9212 -408.0767) rotate(85.1016)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-6"
          x1="939.1844"
          y1="408.3795"
          x2="939.1844"
          y2="315.0461"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#2d3d54"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.1808"
            stop-color="#7b7c84"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3611"
            stop-color="#c1b6b0"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4899"
            stop-color="#edd9cb"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5551"
            stop-color="#fee7d5"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.765"
            stop-color="#fef1e6"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-7"
          x1="902.9354"
          y1="401.3201"
          x2="954.2108"
          y2="401.3201"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 13"
          x1="1116.3619"
          y1="414.6718"
          x2="1116.3619"
          y2="380.2045"
          gradientTransform="matrix(-0.9977, -0.0673, -0.0673, 0.9977, 2069.0162, 74.1349)"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#fee7d5"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#ffc5a9"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13-2"
          x1="205.2625"
          y1="396.867"
          x2="214.9458"
          y2="396.867"
          gradientTransform="matrix(0.992, 0.126, -0.126, 0.992, 801.135, -44.0006)"
          xlink:href="#Gradiente_sem_nome_13"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_13-3"
          x1="1131.8728"
          y1="395.588"
          x2="1141.556"
          y2="395.588"
          gradientTransform="matrix(-0.992, -0.126, -0.126, 0.992, 2090.6347, 119.7773)"
          xlink:href="#Gradiente_sem_nome_13"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-8"
          x1="885.4584"
          y1="359.9616"
          x2="950.5125"
          y2="348.4908"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-9"
          x1="899.0038"
          y1="360.5009"
          x2="980.0221"
          y2="360.5009"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#f27075"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5248"
            stop-color="#2d6cea"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.5932"
            stop-color="#457dec"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7376"
            stop-color="#82a8f3"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.9447"
            stop-color="#e4ecfc"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-10"
          x1="901.7687"
          y1="404.3587"
          x2="955.1403"
          y2="404.3587"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-11"
          x1="855.3938"
          y1="472.4557"
          x2="988.2765"
          y2="449.0249"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-12"
          x1="957.1854"
          y1="420.1377"
          x2="966.852"
          y2="420.1377"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-13"
          x1="911.3371"
          y1="400.3877"
          x2="948.8464"
          y2="400.3877"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-14"
          x1="890.8894"
          y1="434.7924"
          x2="902.9896"
          y2="434.7924"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-15"
          x1="864.5134"
          y1="493.2369"
          x2="864.5134"
          y2="480.9984"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-16"
          x1="936.2392"
          y1="458.2563"
          x2="949.047"
          y2="458.2563"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-17"
          x1="880.6081"
          y1="418.679"
          x2="892.6152"
          y2="418.679"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-18"
          x1="896.9408"
          y1="366.1418"
          x2="896.9408"
          y2="351.4266"
          gradientTransform="translate(1018.2501 -599.6067) rotate(75.4121)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-19"
          x1="928.1403"
          y1="464.5368"
          x2="952.6186"
          y2="464.5368"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-20"
          x1="957.7139"
          y1="347.5472"
          x2="816.6332"
          y2="103.1882"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#4eca7a"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.047"
            stop-color="#4dc278"
            stop-opacity="0.939"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3699"
            stop-color="#438c69"
            stop-opacity="0.5406"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.6354"
            stop-color="#3c645d"
            stop-opacity="0.2487"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.8302"
            stop-color="#384b57"
            stop-opacity="0.0684"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.9336"
            stop-color="#364254"
            stop-opacity="0"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-21"
          x1="952.9233"
          y1="454.2961"
          x2="1034.4804"
          y2="454.2961"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#401737"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.076"
            stop-color="#433e45"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.2046"
            stop-color="#487a5c"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3143"
            stop-color="#4ba56c"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.3994"
            stop-color="#4dc076"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4494"
            stop-color="#4eca7a"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="Gradiente_sem_nome_8"
          data-name="Gradiente sem nome 8"
          x1="919.4737"
          y1="344.12"
          x2="1010.7447"
          y2="344.12"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#401737"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.1108"
            stop-color="#411e3a"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.277"
            stop-color="#423341"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.4782"
            stop-color="#45554e"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.7066"
            stop-color="#488360"
          />
          <stop
            offset="0.955"
            stop-color="#4dbe76"
          />
          <stop
            offset="1"
            stop-color="#4eca7a"
          />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-22"
          x1="997.7087"
          y1="458.4906"
          x2="997.7087"
          y2="452.282"
          gradientTransform="translate(1142.391 -631.7504) rotate(73.0472)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-23"
          x1="941.5251"
          y1="595.9957"
          x2="1022.4679"
          y2="499.5318"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-24"
          x1="988.6073"
          y1="623.721"
          x2="988.6073"
          y2="606.0954"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-25"
          x1="991.6126"
          y1="614.8744"
          x2="991.6126"
          y2="600.1377"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-26"
          x1="994.8687"
          y1="497.0958"
          x2="994.8687"
          y2="481.8919"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-27"
          x1="975.0767"
          y1="595.5689"
          x2="975.0767"
          y2="584.3129"
          gradientTransform="translate(1479.6015 -431.9493) rotate(85.1016)"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-2"
        />
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-28"
          x1="821.4987"
          y1="382.8428"
          x2="816.8826"
          y2="385.073"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        >
          <stop
            offset="0"
            stop-color="#fff"
          />
          <stop offset="1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient
          id="linear-gradient-29"
          x1="821.8294"
          y1="381.4053"
          x2="828.1228"
          y2="381.4053"
          xlink:href="#linear-gradient-28"
        />
      </defs>
      <g style="isolation: isolate">
        <g id="corda">
          <path
            d="M10.1381,523.7887a129.9984,129.9984,0,0,1,23.4478-28.0481,137.2,137.2,0,0,1,14.4833-11.4312,131.4185,131.4185,0,0,1,16.0282-9.3232A122.8008,122.8008,0,0,1,81.43,468.0534c2.9868-.9311,6.0182-1.7484,9.0912-2.4311q4.6143-.999,9.3441-1.5545a84.3237,84.3237,0,0,1,19.1751-.1527,64.1678,64.1678,0,0,1,19.0137,5.03,54.4889,54.4889,0,0,1,8.8048,4.9313,51.29,51.29,0,0,1,7.7448,6.6289,50.2482,50.2482,0,0,1,3.3489,3.8652l1.3657,1.7187c.416.5431.8833,1.0634,1.3227,1.5959,1.8007,2.11,3.7375,4.1481,5.7635,6.1129a126.0336,126.0336,0,0,0,27.638,19.9649A122.0777,122.0777,0,0,0,225.73,525.7655a88.8416,88.8416,0,0,0,32.9611,1.2545,76.21,76.21,0,0,0,7.9761-1.7469,72.5878,72.5878,0,0,0,7.7339-2.557,77.53,77.53,0,0,0,14.45-7.5716,100.2369,100.2369,0,0,0,23.87-23.0338,141.4885,141.4885,0,0,0,9.3889-14.208c1.4575-2.4627,2.7775-4.9956,4.1448-7.5432,1.4553-2.7422,2.9114-5.4836,4.4589-8.1762q4.6074-8.0952,9.8-15.8476,5.2212-7.7251,11.0333-15.0424A213.69,213.69,0,0,1,377.2119,404.11a180.8723,180.8723,0,0,1,30.526-22.0113,139.9645,139.9645,0,0,1,35.2769-14.33,104.4177,104.4177,0,0,1,38.5771-2.51,92.4736,92.4736,0,0,1,36.7547,12.78,110.5846,110.5846,0,0,1,28.7541,25.4918,144.872,144.872,0,0,1,10.9053,15.5219c1.6008,2.7056,3.2016,5.4117,4.6519,8.1864l1.113,2.0693,1.0443,2.0983,2.05,4.1369a222.2631,222.2631,0,0,0,17.4,30.2127,121.9379,121.9379,0,0,0,22.8687,25.18c8.7006,6.9742,18.6615,12.1735,29.2445,13.9654a50.7067,50.7067,0,0,0,15.9747.2238,56.6979,56.6979,0,0,0,15.497-4.6532,78.1028,78.1028,0,0,0,26.11-20.4673,99.4568,99.4568,0,0,0,9.81-13.8993c1.4532-2.45,2.7643-4.9855,4.01-7.5516l1.8876-4.0331c.6459-1.3956,1.3241-2.7754,1.9944-4.1585A228.387,228.387,0,0,1,730.51,418.6864a166.08,166.08,0,0,1,24.5238-27.74,121.2878,121.2878,0,0,1,14.8163-11.38,96.6508,96.6508,0,0,1,16.6384-8.7412,80.1964,80.1964,0,0,1,37.0089-5.8268c12.5584,1,24.5831,5.0685,35.5046,10.7034a148.2251,148.2251,0,0,1,30.0062,20.9443,250.8421,250.8421,0,0,1,25.2756,26.0567,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-2.2388,1.9964l-.0118-.0127a247.1063,247.1063,0,0,0-25.9278-24.6038,149.2618,149.2618,0,0,0-29.6935-19.15c-10.57-5.0008-21.9084-8.3606-33.3851-8.8706a72.891,72.891,0,0,0-33.3863,6.2489,88.3078,88.3078,0,0,0-14.9883,8.4326,112.4246,112.4246,0,0,0-13.4363,10.9474A144.7821,144.7821,0,0,0,749.3,410.4347a174.8567,174.8567,0,0,0-10.548,14.0031A217.9769,217.9769,0,0,0,721.4548,455.05c-.61,1.3342-1.2277,2.6648-1.8134,4.009l-1.8452,4.1693c-1.3191,2.8651-2.7168,5.6987-4.2729,8.45a110.8506,110.8506,0,0,1-10.6422,15.7293,88.3839,88.3839,0,0,1-29.8157,24.1271,69.0633,69.0633,0,0,1-18.8281,5.937,64.6783,64.6783,0,0,1-29.6086-2.2692,70.4885,70.4885,0,0,1-9.1971-3.605,88.2479,88.2479,0,0,1-16.52-10.25,135.2446,135.2446,0,0,1-25.883-27.606A225.59,225.59,0,0,1,554.0734,441.79l-1.9915-3.9177-.9819-1.9264-1.0427-1.8875c-1.358-2.5383-2.8467-4.9868-4.3273-7.4382a130.3666,130.3666,0,0,0-9.9445-13.85,95.8119,95.8119,0,0,0-25.1086-21.86,77.3089,77.3089,0,0,0-30.941-10.4064,85.0584,85.0584,0,0,0-16.4912-.2871,102.278,102.278,0,0,0-16.4418,2.7483,124.3046,124.3046,0,0,0-31.251,12.85,165.08,165.08,0,0,0-27.766,20.183,197.75,197.75,0,0,0-23.6736,25.2571q-5.3815,6.8186-10.2329,14.0516-4.8208,7.2434-9.1024,14.8357c-1.4388,2.5216-2.7905,5.0918-4.1444,7.66-1.4657,2.75-2.9455,5.5342-4.5528,8.2408a157.572,157.572,0,0,1-10.5269,15.8081,112.9818,112.9818,0,0,1-27.968,26.5646,93.3378,93.3378,0,0,1-17.5092,8.9514,89.2817,89.2817,0,0,1-19.0534,4.9525,102.9441,102.9441,0,0,1-38.6288-2.0733,134.4123,134.4123,0,0,1-35.1971-14.2581,139.3158,139.3158,0,0,1-29.8981-23.1059c-2.2146-2.29-4.3481-4.68-6.3677-7.2067-.4977-.6411-1.0125-1.2589-1.4918-1.9224l-1.3794-1.8546a37.9246,37.9246,0,0,0-2.4531-3.024,42.1378,42.1378,0,0,0-12.4763-9.4316c-9.5687-4.7971-21.0189-6.2548-32.3023-5.4208a107.2722,107.2722,0,0,0-33.3739,8.3137,134.2376,134.2376,0,0,0-30.1162,17.8426,136.8208,136.8208,0,0,0-24.7194,25.2979,1.5014,1.5014,0,0,1-2.48-1.6879Z"
            transform="translate(-9.9166 -135.4679)"
            fill="url(#Gradiente_sem_nome_150)"
          />
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

see the full code
https://codepen.io/yung-silva/pen/OKGjpJ

I need it to be a `smooth wave` effect animation, but I couldn't find anything that would help me

here are the closest references you can find

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/742876/screenshots/3631385/moon-walk.gif

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/123785/screenshots/3789858/spaceman_final.gif

https://media1.giphy.com/media/8lNaZuf2ZmF54oalhP/giphy.gif

can anybody help me?

Comment: @RobertLongson It's too big to put in the question :(

Comment: @enxaneta Can you show me how you would do it in practice?

Comment: @RobertLongson ok, I fixed that already.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified a lot your code and of coarse you may want to draw the curves yourself but the main idea is this: You are animating the `d` attribute between the first value the second value and back to the first value. The values are separated with semicolons ;

Both curves have the same number of points and the same commands.

```html
<svg viewBox="-25 175 350 125" >

 <path fill="#FFD700" d="M-4.751, 226.777 C-4.751, 226.777 6.687, 195.258 32.406, 195.845 C58.125, 196.432 67.631, 246.301 86.290, 244.424 C104.949, 242.547 115.138, 195.234 151.554, 195.833 C187.970, 196.432 201.390, 253.554 224.304, 252.332 C247.218, 251.110 253.309, 230.298 272.076, 229.988 C290.843, 229.678 304.833, 247.054 304.833, 247.054 C304.833, 247.054 292.097, 234.558 272.651, 234.000 C253.205, 233.442 250.069, 258.163 223.724, 257.721 C197.379, 257.279 184.875, 204.588 150.040, 202.706 C115.205, 200.824 115.832, 246.615 85.154, 248.152 C56.262, 249.599 58.124, 203.333 32.405, 201.451 C6.374, 199.546 -4.751, 226.777 -4.751, 226.777 Z">
  <animate
    dur='15s'
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName='d'      
    repeatCount='indefinite'
           values="M-4.751, 226.777 C-4.751, 226.777 6.687, 195.258 32.406, 195.845 C58.125, 196.432 67.631, 246.301 86.290, 244.424 C104.949, 242.547 115.138, 195.234 151.554, 195.833 C187.970, 196.432 201.390, 253.554 224.304, 252.332 C247.218, 251.110 253.309, 230.298 272.076, 229.988 C290.843, 229.678 304.833, 247.054 304.833, 247.054 C304.833, 247.054 292.097, 234.558 272.651, 234.000 C253.205, 233.442 250.069, 258.163 223.724, 257.721 C197.379, 257.279 184.875, 204.588 150.040, 202.706 C115.205, 200.824 115.832, 246.615 85.154, 248.152 C56.262, 249.599 58.124, 203.333 32.405, 201.451 C6.374, 199.546 -4.751, 226.777 -4.751, 226.777 Z;
             M-4.751, 226.777 C-4.751, 226.777 7.982, 259.282 33.660, 257.726 C54.360, 256.472 64.462, 211.828 83.215, 211.828 C120.224, 211.828 113.653, 267.321 150.041, 268.888 C179.188, 270.143 195.166, 219.928 218.079, 218.706 C240.993, 217.484 253.884, 257.280 272.652, 256.970 C291.420, 256.660 304.833, 246.275 304.833, 246.275 C304.833, 246.275 292.725, 261.918 273.279, 261.360 C253.833, 260.802 238.152, 222.469 218.707, 223.724 C193.126, 225.374 182.325, 273.726 150.041, 273.726 C115.155, 273.726 117.030, 217.795 86.352, 219.332 C57.460, 220.779 61.261, 261.359 33.034, 263.241 C6.989, 264.979 -4.751, 226.777 -4.751, 226.777 Z;      
                   
                   M-4.751, 226.777 C-4.751, 226.777 6.687, 195.258 32.406, 195.845 C58.125, 196.432 67.631, 246.301 86.290, 244.424 C104.949, 242.547 115.138, 195.234 151.554, 195.833 C187.970, 196.432 201.390, 253.554 224.304, 252.332 C247.218, 251.110 253.309, 230.298 272.076, 229.988 C290.843, 229.678 304.833, 247.054 304.833, 247.054 C304.833, 247.054 292.097, 234.558 272.651, 234.000 C253.205, 233.442 250.069, 258.163 223.724, 257.721 C197.379, 257.279 184.875, 204.588 150.040, 202.706 C115.205, 200.824 115.832, 246.615 85.154, 248.152 C56.262, 249.599 58.124, 203.333 32.405, 201.451 C6.374, 199.546 -4.751, 226.777 -4.751, 226.777 Z" />  
    
  </path>
 


</svg>
```

Comment: [https://codepen.io/yung-silva/pen/QeXNyd](https://codepen.io/yung-silva/pen/QeXNyd) can you tell me why mine is not working? is jumping from one value to another without smooth transition effect

Comment: It's important to have the same number of points and the same commands. You don't have the same commands

Comment: How did you set the second value/line different but similar to the first?

Comment: After drawing it on Illustrator I've transformed all the commands to upperCase cubic Bézier `C`

Comment: sorry i didn't quite understand your answer.

Could you explain me in more detail?

After you drew the line in illustrator, you exported and already got the first value, correct?

but how did you change the line in illustrator and keep the same amount of values?

Comment: when i change the line / drawing in illustrator and export it already exports with different values ​​even though it has the same amount of points

Comment: Please read this article: [How SVG Shape Morphing Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/)

Comment: I already know how it works, but the problem is when it comes to exporting and drawing the second form, even with the same amount of points, the values ​​of the attribute `d` come out with different amount.

could you try with my vector?

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMA7UKT4rbHh1wcfuUulx0eeVH-Tx3Fb/view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMA7UKT4rbHh1wcfuUulx0eeVH-Tx3Fb/view)

Comment: @enxaneta Love the waves